# Android OpenGL deltaTime Measure issue

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm measuring deltaTime like that:

```
deltaTime = (System.nanoTime()-startTime) / 1000000000.0f;
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
```

But I'm always getting different float values and because of that my game is stuttering.What can be the problem of that?

```
09-03 03:51:59.219: D/a(21807): 0.017184043
09-03 03:51:59.234: D/a(21807): 0.016405167
09-03 03:51:59.249: D/a(21807): 0.018071748
09-03 03:51:59.269: D/a(21807): 0.015293334
09-03 03:51:59.284: D/a(21807): 0.016080335
09-03 03:51:59.299: D/a(21807): 0.018669458
09-03 03:51:59.314: D/a(21807): 0.014720625
09-03 03:51:59.334: D/a(21807): 0.01605596
09-03 03:51:59.349: D/a(21807): 0.017086169
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're executing this code every frame, that means this is the time it takes to render 1 frame.

You should be doing your calculations based on `( x distance per second ) * deltaTime`, so you will get a smooth animation based on how many frames per second.

Comment: Yes i'm exactly doing that.For example i'm using this code to scroll my screen render.guiCam.position.x+=dunya.CONSTANT*deltaTime;

Comment: Sorry, not really sure what the problem is then.. Try logging the position and see if the values are smoothly interpolating

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pseudo code fragment from "Beginning Android Games":

```
float lastFrameTime = currentTime();
while(!userQuit()) {
    float deltaTime = currentTime() – lastFrameTime;
    lastFrameTime = currentTime();
    currentScreen.updateState(input, deltaTime);
    currentScreen.present(graphics, audio, deltaTime);
}
```

Not sure if this is going to help...

Comment: I'm already using that framework :).I have problem with this schema.

Answer (score 0):

Beginning Android Games isn't a great book.

If you measure delta at every frame, your calculations will use a different value every time. This produces very bad results with projectile motion and non-trivial physics. For the best results, fix delta to a reasonable value (i.e 1/60), and make the thread wait at the end of all drawing if it's been less than 1/60 since the start.